# Spring Boot 2.2.0 and Maven Plugin trouble

Tags: maven, spring-boot

I have two projects. One as follow ( say project 1 ):

```
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.3.RELEASE</version>
    <relativePath/> 
</parent>
```

And second ( say project 2 ) as follow:

```
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.2.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <relativePath/> 
</parent>
```

Both have this:

```
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Well, project 1 is running fine. I can see the Spring Plugin v. 2.0.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT in my .M2 repo folder.

Project 2 is throwing the follow error:

```
***************************
APPLICATION FAILED TO START
***************************

Description:

An attempt was made to call the method org.springframework.plugin.core.PluginRegistry.getPluginFor(Ljava/lang/Object;Lorg/springframework/plugin/core/Plugin;)Lorg/springframework/plugin/core/Plugin; but it does not exist. Its class, org.springframework.plugin.core.PluginRegistry, is available from the following locations:

    jar:file:/.../.m2/repository/org/springframework/plugin/spring-plugin-core/2.0.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT/spring-plugin-core-2.0.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar!/org/springframework/plugin/core/PluginRegistry.class

It was loaded from the following location:

    file:/.../.m2/repository/org/springframework/plugin/spring-plugin-core/2.0.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT/spring-plugin-core-2.0.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar


Action:

Correct the classpath of your application so that it contains a single, compatible version of org.springframework.plugin.core.PluginRegistry
```

When I try to force a version to Maven plugin in project 2 POM, I see the classic yellow warning saying I'm overriding the managed version 2.2.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT but there's no 2.2.0 version to Maven Plugin.

The strange is that I'm was able to run this project until yesterday....

Can someone tell me what are going wrong?

NOTE: When I downgrade project 2 to 2.0.3.RELEASE all start to work.

Comment: Is there a reason why are you using a `-SNAPSHOT` version?

Comment: Actualy there is no reason. Must I use v2.1.3 ?

Comment: I would use a released version and not a `-SNAPSHOT` only if you are trying special things. So I would suggest to use the most recent release version which is 2.1.3

Comment: If so, I must consider this a cold case. You rule!

Comment: Maybe I misunderstand you answer. It depends if you have  to stick with 2.0.X line if not upgrade...

Comment: You undrstood cleary and gave me a good answer. I just need to downgrade a little and all is done. Thankyou

Comment: The error is found in the Swagger and Spring versions. You have to work on the versions that can be compatible.

Answer (score 7):

When we use any dependencies(other than Spring boot provided) in our project, we need to provided spring transaction core plug-in to resolve this issue.

Kindly try the below dependency and version is compatible to your Spring Boot version.

Spring Transaction Core Dependency:

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.plugin</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-plugin-core</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.0.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
```

Comment: What is the mission (function) of `spring-plugin-core` ? It is not clear to me. Can you explain a little more? I'm not much confortable just copy/past code snippets. The @khmarbaise comment to downgrade actualy solved the problem.

Comment: Your answer may be correct just because the upvotes and I'm tempted to accept it but I not actualy tested yet because it already solved by keeping the version in the reseased line avoiding touch the snapshot.

Answer (score 7):

The solution to this problem is simple, you would have imported **Spring Boot Data REST Starter** dependency in your dependency section. just remove it. everything will work fine and absolutely perfect. thank you!

Comment: I can't figure out how do you reach this conclusion and why.

Comment: If I really need `spring-boot-starter-data-rest` then what is your suggestion?

Comment: this was the actual culprit. nothing else like spring core, swagger etc just this. Thanks

Comment: without the dependency, i am unable to resolve RepositoryEventHandler class.